# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent querying

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I know all the Eloquent model querying is in the Laravel documentation and I have read through them to figure this out but can't seem to work my way around it. I am building a recipe application, and I want to get access to a particular profile picture of a user based on an uploaded recipe.

I have a grid of recipes that have been uploaded by various users. The User and Recipe model are below.

**User Model**

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recipe');
}
```

**Recipe Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In my recipe grid, I have the following code in a recipe card.

**Index Blade/View**

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
<img class="recipeProfilePic" src="/storage/profile_pictures/{{What goes here}}" alt=""><a
        href="{{ route('user', $recipe->user_id) }}">
    <small>{{$recipe->author}}</small>
</a>
@endforeach
```

Through the $recipe I can access the name of the creator of that particular recipe like this `$recipe->author`. I am trying to get access to this specific users profile photo too. I want to get something like this `$recipe->author->profile_pic`. (profile_pic is a column in my users table).

How would I go about solving this problem in a simple way? I'm a newcomer to coding and am still working on solving these problems myself. Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could just put a function like `public function author(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); }` in your recipe model and then access it like `$recipe->author->profile_pic`.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It's not able to access it. I get the error, "Trying to get property of non-object". Any thoughts? Do you need more of my code?

Comment: Solved it!! Thank you! You were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$recipe->user->profile_pic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the model by rename `user` to `author` like this:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

or changing view (blade) like this:

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
<img class="recipeProfilePic" src="/storage/profile_pictures/{{What goes here}}" alt=""><a
        href="{{ route('user', $recipe->user_id) }}">
    <small>{{$recipe->user->profile_pic}}</small>
</a>
@endforeach
```